# Create a Plugin to Download Files from Web to Server

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a plugin and want to have a feature where, in the Admin area, the user will click on a link and it will download a theme to the /themes directory on their server. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these private themes? Or themes hosted on wordpress.org? If the latter, WordPress already supports installing themes over HTTP.

Comment: That was just an example. Just creating some local plugins to help myself with development. I figured it out using fopen/fread/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm... You are writing the plugin or thinking about it? Could you show us some stuff that you already did? You should check the permissions on the server where you want to upload the files. Then - in case - change chmod, upload and then change chmod back for sec. reasons. [Maybe the update class will help you a little further.](http://www.wpajax.com/articles/wordpress-upgrade-class-for-commercial-or-client-plugins)